# How do I detect if the public key in a digital certificate is modified?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, digital-signature

I know how the basic process of digital certificate, but how do I detect if the public key in a digital certificate is modified?

Comment: This is not very appropriate question, as it asks about something, that is the core of the design of digital certificates. Just carefully reading what they are should answer this. I believe this question may be useful however for people making a quick google, so you have an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

The digital signature underneath the certificate - generated by the Certificate Authority (CA) that issued the certificate - will not verify if the public key is changed. The only way someone could "change" the public key without the certificate failing verification is if the adversary compromises a trusted CA, or maybe more exactly your CA depending on how closely you inspect the certificate.

In more detail, the CA has a private key in possession and the corresponding public key is installed in all operating systems and browsers. The CA uses the private key to sign a certificate and then the browser / OS checks the signature using the trusted public key. If the signature is correct, the public key in the certificate cannot have been changed.

It is possible that more *intermediate* certificates are used, where the parent certificate can be used to verify the child certificate. This is called a chain of trust, starting with a leaf certificate and ending with a certificate in the trust store.